# timer in a console application C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you add a timer to a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-console-application)

i have a console application. Now to the timer function I want to pass a streamwriter object so that i can write a certain set of data after elapse of say like 10 seconds. How do i do it??

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the streamwriter in, use a member variable.

Comment: I didn't get you.. If you trying to say to declare new streamwriter variable in the thread method then it's a problem because i have to use the same file for writing operations in the main method too. N it gives an error that file already being used.