# Timer executes only once

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have an UCMA console app and I want it to report "I am alive" signal by writting current timestamp to the database. To do that I use timer:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Random r = new Random();
   System.Threading.TimerCallback TimerDelegate = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(TimerCallBack);
   Timer TimerItem = new Timer(TimerDelegate, null, 0, r.Next(10000, 25000));


   UCMASampleForwardIncomingCall ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall = new UCMASampleForwardIncomingCall() 
   ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall.Run();

}
```

`TimerCallBack` writes the data to the database, `ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall` is the "main" method of the program, all is important at this stage that after initial configuration it waits for an event. But the code above executes the timer only once...
I was thinking about putting the `ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall` on separate thread:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Random r = new Random();
   System.Threading.TimerCallback TimerDelegate = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(TimerCallBack);
   Timer TimerItem = new Timer(TimerDelegate, null, 0, r.Next(10000, 25000));
   Thread callThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall.Run));
   callThread.Start();
```

but still the timer executes only once. I've read ["How-to set timer" thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application) but I'm still confused here...

EDIT: using `GC.keepAlive(TimerItem)` solved the issue.

edit 2: or not... after few events the timer stops, probably when there was exception caught in the ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall

edit 3: currently working with:

```
     public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     Random r = new Random();
     Timer TimerItem = new Timer(TimerCallBack, null, 0, r.Next(10000, 15000));
      ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall.Run();
     GC.KeepAlive(TimerItem);
  }

    private static void TimerCallBack(Object o)
    {.... more code.....}
```

But I'm not holding my hopes too high...

Comment: The upvoted answers in that SO question all have the same bug you do.  The `TimerItem` variable is not enough to prevent the Timer object from getting garbage collected.  Store it in a static field or put GC.KeepAlive(TimerItem) at the end of your Main() method.

Comment: Thank you, could you please put it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue on the longer run: yes, it does run but after few events the timer stops anyway. :(

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment on your question because of reputation under 50 :D but I think it's better to define a field for your timer because if callback is a static field then it's root object needs to be defined in same scope. Code will be like this and I hope this will help you.

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // timer properties will be set here
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    ucmaSampleForwardIncomingCall.Run();
}

private static void timer_Tick(Object o) {}
```