# Cant get a bool to work in this context

Tags: c#, timer, boolean

Im sure this has a very simple solution, but I am very bad at this...
I want the "time up!" text to display only after the 2 min timer, as appose to both when it begins and after the 2 mins, I thought a bool would do it, but i cant get it to work, i think its to do with the "static void" "public void" stuff but im not sure, any help would be massively appreciated!

```
class Program
{
    bool a = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Define thread
        Console.WriteLine("Start, you have 2 mins!");

        //120000 is milliseconds, so every 120 seconds it will run the thread function
        System.Threading.Timer threadingTimer = new Timer(run, 0, 0, 120000);
        a = true;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //define thread function
    public void run(object args)
    {
        if (a = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Times Up!");
        }

    }
}
```

if there is a simpler way of achiving this then that is also appreciated, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Does that code even compile? You can't do an assignment in an if-statement like that. Please explain what you mean by "can't get it to work".

Comment: Why do you need the the Boolean value at all? `a` seems always to be `true`, when `run` is executed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes it compiles. See my comment on *assignment expressions*.

Comment: My bad, I'm so used to just upping "all warnings as errors" in my own projects that I didn't think that this was not an error, just a warning.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your current code is as follows: The following `if statement` will always be `true`.

```
if (a = true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Times Up!");
}
```

**Why is that?** In the `()` of an `if statement` you should pass a valid boolean expression. When you write `a = true` what you are doing is

1. Assigning `true` to `a`
2. Evaluating `a` (with its new value) it in the context of the `if`. As `a` is of type `bool` it does compile.

Therefore the `if` is always met and you always get the print.

What you probably meant is writing `a == true`. The difference is that `==` is the equals operator instead of the assignment operator.

---

By the way if you look visual studio gives you the following message:

> Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = ?

Comment: @downvoter. In C# an assignment is a valid expression! It yields the assigned value as result of the expression. See: [Simple assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx). It says: *The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to the left operand.*

Comment: ok, that did solve an issue that VS was showing me, thanks for that but what i neglected to mention in my question is that im getting this compile error...  
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.run(object)'

this is in reference to the "run" in the system.threading line, and the "a" in the a = true line below...

Answer (score -1):

try the answer from this thread [How do you add a timer to a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application) by @Real Caz

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace timer
{
class Program
{
    static Timer timer = new Timer(1000); 
    static int i = 10; //this is for 10 seconds only change it as you will

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        timer.Elapsed+=timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        i--;
        Console.WriteLine("Time Remaining: " + i.ToString());
        if (i == 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Times up!");
            timer.Close();
            timer.Dispose();
        }

        GC.Collect();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: not using the same method, but like i say, new to programming, this seems to work really well, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start, you have 10 seconds!");
        ShowMessageAfterDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), "Time has lappsed!").Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task ShowMessageAfterDelay(TimeSpan timeSpan, string message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeSpan);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```