# how to use a class property in xaml in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, android-databinding

I want a property from c# class in a text view in XAML. How to do this? I want to show when the user started his job end how long he works (Every day after he's logged in).

Here's my code:

XAML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"

    />

    android:text="You're at work since:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:id="@+id/entryTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"/>
    <TextView
            android:text= Today you work already:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"/>
```

C# class I want to do the binding with

```
public LoginViewModel(ILogin login)
{
    _loginService = login;
    _appVariables = new AppVariables();
    GoToDashboard = new Interaction<Unit, Unit>();
    var canLogin = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.UserName, x => x.Password, LoginInputValidator.Validate);
    LoginCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => { await TryLogin(); }, canLogin);
}

private async Task<IObservable<bool>> TryLogin()
{
    var lg = await _loginService.Login(_userName, _password);
    if (lg)
    {
        _appVariables.UserName = UserName;
        _appVariables.logDate = DateTime.Now;
        _appVariables.isLogged = true;

        await GoToDashboard.Handle(Unit.Default);
    }
    return Observable.Return(lg);
}
```

c# another class

```
public class AppVariables
{
    public bool isLogged;
    public DateTime logDate;
    public DateTime offDate;
    public string UserName;
}
```

I've tried with this

```
BindingContext = this;  
InitializeComponent();
```

but it's always red, I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: What's the red error you get? And you can't use binding in Xamarin.Android. Data-binding is available in Xamarin.forms project.

Comment: Cannot resolve bindingcontext and initalize component. I've got a separate class that keeps the time of logging and class with instance of that. Only thing I miss is how to display this in xaml that the user began his work that time.

Comment: Are you writing a xamarin.android project or a xamarin.forms project?

Comment: xamarain.android

Comment: So, can you get the textView in code behind and set the text of textView like: `TextView textV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.timeTextView);` and then
            `textV.Text = "Today you work already:" + //the time you want to display`

Comment: And what to write in xaml? And what to do with "cannot resolve findviewbyid"?

Comment: No change to xaml, just build your project.

Comment: And what with red FindViewById?

Comment: Build your project directly and it will work.

Comment: Now I have this. Build successful, but app crashes.

Comment: What changes did you make to your code? You should find which line caused the crash and any stack trace?

Comment: _appVariables.UserName = UserName;
                _appVariables.logDate = DateTime.Now;
                _appVariables.isLogged = true;
                 await GoToDashboard.Handle(Unit.Default);
                 TextView textV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.entryTextView);
                 textV.Text = "You're at work since:" + _appVariables.logDate;

Comment: had to do this to avoid red: private T FindViewById<T>(int timeTextView)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Comment: You have to add `TextView textV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.entryTextView); textV.Text = "You're at work since:" + _appVariables.logDate;` in the Activity instead of model class.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) What to do if I want the date to be displyed in new line?

Comment: Use `textV.Text = "Today you work already:"+ "\n" + "your text";`

Comment: Used it, but doesn't look as nice as I wanted, second line is longer, and first part of  text is not really in the center of the line

Comment: Set the TextAlignment  to center: `textV.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;`.

Comment: Does your problem solved? I list some points in out chat as an answer and can you please mark that answer so that we can help more people with same problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another issue I have, is to count timespan between now and begin of work. I want it to be refreshed every minute.

Comment: Use `TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now - start;`. Check the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521366/getting-time-span-between-two-times-in-c)

Comment: Yes, but it has to be an updated time span between now and the beginning.

Comment: You can use a timer to get the time span every minute and then update the label's text. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875791/adding-a-timer-to-a-xamarin-app-c) about how to use a timer in xamarin.forms. Can you please accept my answer if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

1.To access the element in the axml in Xamarin.android project, you can use:

```
TextView textV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.entryTextView);
```

2.`TextView textV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.entryTextView);` should be added in the Activity class instead of model class.

3.To start a new line in label/textView, you can use `"/n"`

4.To center the text in the textView, you can set the `TextAlignment`:

`textV.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;`