# Countdown timer system.timers problem xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Now i updated the code and im not getting errors, problem is its not counting

```
   private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private int _countSeconds;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _countSeconds = 5;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
                          
    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _countSeconds--;
        CountLabel.Text = _countSeconds.ToString();

        if (_countSeconds == 0)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        
       
    }
                     
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the OnTimedEvent method i need to specify arguments when calling it. I just dont know what to pass in but i would like it to be called from a button but no clue what system timers elapsedeventargs e is. Looked on youtube, reddit, stackoverflow and microsoft. No real explanation or help anywhere.

Heres my MainPage.xaml

```
<Label Text="Count" x:Name="CountLabel"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large"></Label>
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? On build or run? Try giving the whole error message. In your example you have one curly brace `}` more than you should.

Comment: What is the specific error code/message and what line is causing it?  Why do you have a `void Main` in a XF Page?

Comment: Visual Studio can typical help writing event handler methods. After typing `+=´ press TAB once or twice. But the methods seems correct.

Comment: @Michael removed curly brace after updating code

Comment: @Michael removed main and put the code in mainpage. i did autocomplete thank you. Now its not counting tho

Comment: @Jason moved the code to mainpage thanks

Comment: you need to update your Label on the main thread - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Comment: @Jason This shit just made my day, thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Device.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Device_StartTimer_System_TimeSpan_System_Func_System_Boolean__) instead of System.Timers in Xamarin.Forms.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private int _countSeconds  = 5 ;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
         {
             _countSeconds--;
             CountLabel.Text = _countSeconds.ToString();
             return Convert.ToBoolean(_countSeconds);
         });
    }
```

I think this question and answers help you.
[How do I add a timer in Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875791/how-do-i-add-a-timer-in-xamarin)

Comment: return Convert.ToBoolean(_countSeconds); is this for checking if the timer is running or what?

Comment: Convert.ToBoolean() returns true if value is not zero; otherwise, false.
So , the timer is running while _countseconds > 0.
When _countseconds reach 0 , the timer stop.

Comment: There's also `System.Threading.Timer`. It's an absolutely horrible API, but it can at least be cancelled.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio can typical help writing event handler methods. After typing `+=´ press TAB once or twice. But the methods seems correct. – Michael

you need to update your Label on the main thread - see learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread – Jason

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Andrew dont know how to mark a comment as solution so i thought id comment and mark it as the solution to end post